# How do I render a background image as a sky in blender 2.7x

Tags: rendering, node-editor

I followed a blender 2.5 tutorial for rendering a background image as a sky. It does not work in blender 2.7.

Tutorial link: http://vimeo.com/18689703

Here are a couple of pictures of what happens.

[image: Sky appears around rendered scene instead of inside it]

The sky appears around the rendered scene instead of appearing as an actual sky inside the rendered scene.

[image: Rendered sky]

The rendered image's sky only appears as the gray shaded sky. The image of the sky that I tried to add does not appear as if it is a real sky in the rendered scene.

I want the sky to appear like this:
[image: Sky in blender 2.5 tutorial]

Sky inside the rendered scene instead of around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Blender Render you set the transparency in the shading panel.

[image]

Comment: In 2.78 the shading panel doesn't have an Alpha pulldown menu.

Comment: @davidparks21 in 2.79 it is still like that. What render engine are you using, this option only exists in blender render.

Comment: I see now, I was trying to get it working in the game-engine, it must be different there.

Answer (score 1):

If using Cycles, you need to switch you film to transparent in the render setting panel:

[image]

Also, there also seems to be a bug in the compositor; rendering at less than 100% of your render dimensions doesn't similarly scale down input images. So you'll need to render at 100%.

Comment: I don't see the film settings in the render setting panel. Do you know how to get the film settings to appear?

Comment: Oh this setting only applies for Cycles render engine.. if you're using Blender Internal, see sambler's answer.

Comment: I don't think that's a bug.. Why would it scale down the input images?

Comment: If you're mixing a render layer with an input image, won't it the results differ when the render layer suddenly changes size? I'm thinking of a specific case where I translated/scaled duplicates of a render layer across an input image; had it all lining up just how I wanted it, and it fell apart when I bumped the render up to 100%