# How do I make my background image in VSE visible?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, import, image, video, transparency

I imported my background image. It shows in default view but won't show in VSE, how do I make it visible?

Comment: 3d view and the vse are two very different, almost unrelated things. What are you trying to accomplish? Make a video with a background image? Add a background image to your animation in 3d view?

Comment: Make a video with a background image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The background image on the viewport is for reference only. It will not render.

Add a strip with your background image, place it under the scene strip, and make the blend mode for the scene strip **Alpha Over**

[image]

To make the background transparent please read: [How do I render a background image as a sky in blender 2.7x](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15816/how-do-i-render-a-background-image-as-a-sky-in-blender-2-7x)

Comment: hey cegaton, thanks but it still isn't showing

Comment: Please edit your question and add images that show what your current settings are, and explain in detail what you've tried