# How to render a sky in game engine?

Tags: rendering, game-engine, properties

I tried to follow this question.

[How do I render a background image as a sky in blender 2.7x](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15816/how-do-i-render-a-background-image-as-a-sky-in-blender-2-7x)

I've also tried to follow a number of older tutorials and posts, but my shading panel doesn't contain an Alpha option as mentioned in that answer.

Also, under `World` I don't see a commonly referred to "Paper Sky", "Blend Sky", and "Real Sky" option, which causes me to lose context in most tutorials.

You can see below that I got the picture in, but it doesn't get rendered, and I can't find a tutorial or Q&A answer that seems to match the settings I see in Blender 2.78. So either things have changed or I've broken things beyond recognition (the later seems quite plausible). :)

Also, I'm rendering this in the game engine if that matters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Lookup the word Skybox or Skydome.  I'm sure you'll find the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 Ah, I see, I can't follow these simple rendering tutorials because of the nature of the game engine, the skybox makes sense. That's the key insight I didn't understand. You can post that as an answer, it's what I needed to know, maybe with this reference link: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Build_a_skybox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 'Scene' actuator in 'Add Background Scene' mode and add a Scene to the background of the current scene. You have lots of options when doing this.

See the example file, where I mixed two scenes and (using Python) I copied the rotation of the 'game' scene camera to the 'skybox' scene camera. Try to read the script, see the logic bricks, explore the scenes and you will understand how this method is powerful, allowing you to make a dynamic skybox in a scene and simply adding it to the main game scene.

http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48431

Alternatively, make a skybox object and parent to a single vertex of your game character. The skybox will follow your character location, but not the rotation, which is good for a sky.